# mysql order by FIELD() not working with value contains spaces

Tags: mysql, sorting, field, whitespace

I am trying to sort rows by specific value of column in mysql, I am using FIELD function, but its not working with values containing spaces.

I tried encoded string such as "United%20States", also FIELD (country, "United", "States")

But none of them are working.

Below is the query snippet I am trying to use:

```
order by FIELD(p.country, "United States")
```

Below one is working (without spaces)

```
order by FIELD(p.country, "Canada")
```

Expecting sort by Country "United States", but its not working

Please help.

Comment: this may help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally

Comment: can you please provide some sample data and expected output, that will help to answer

Comment: @JayShankarGupta I have users table, with country column, where I want to sort users by specific country value. Such as Austrailia, United States etc.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde it doesn't help, my problem with space in value.